# filemtime() constant during execution despite changes to file

Tags: php, filemtime

Try running

```
<?php
  echo filemtime("test.txt")."\n";
  sleep(4);
  file_put_contents("test.txt", "test");
  echo filemtime("test.txt")."\n";
?>
```

For me the command line printed:

```
1343490984
1343490984
```

That can't be right, can it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [`filemtime` documentation](http://php.net/filemtime):

> **Note:** The results of this function are cached. See [`clearstatcache()`](http://php.net/clearstatcache) for more details.

You need to call `clearstatcache()` before you call `filemtime()` again:

```
echo filemtime("test.txt")."\n";
sleep(4);
file_put_contents("test.txt", "test");
clearstatcache();
echo filemtime("test.txt")."\n";
```

Comment: Beat me too it by 5 seconds :p

Comment: I find it redundant for PHP to cache files status when the coder can simply store it in a variable.